# Can You Programatically Link a SQL Server Temp Table To Access?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access, temporary

I am currently creating a temporary table in SQL Server from Microsoft Access to aid in what can be a relatively slow update (Local MSAccess table to SQL Server). I tried using the solution from this question here: [Programatically create ODBC connection and link tables in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3096337/1504882), but I get an error

> The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'TABLE NAME'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

Now I know that I am creating the temp table in the `tempDB` database so I assumed that the following would have worked.

```
Dim tDef As TableDef
Set tDef = db.CreateTableDef("#TEMPTABLENAME")
tDef.Connect = "ODBC;Description=DESCRIPTION;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client XX.X;
                SERVER=SERVERNAME;Trusted_Connection=?;DATABASE=tempdb;"

tDef.SourceTableName = "USERNAME.TEMPTABLENAME"

DATABASE.TableDefs.Append tDef
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After messing with this for a bit I found that using a Global temp table fixed the issue. One extra pound symbol made the difference.

```
Dim tDef As TableDef
Set tDef = db.CreateTableDef("##TEMPTABLENAME")
tDef.Connect = "ODBC;Description=DESCRIPTION;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client XX.X;
            SERVER=SERVERNAME;Trusted_Connection=?;DATABASE=tempdb;"

tDef.SourceTableName = "USERNAME.##TEMPTABLENAME"

DATABASE.TableDefs.Append tDef
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your findings. I was just about to suggest that you have a look at my earlier answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18939600/2144390). :)

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for the additional resources! I believe(assume) that, with temporary table (the single #), the scope of a table definition and the query definition inside of the VBA code are different and thus MSAccess can't find the table to link to in those separate sessions.